# I want to get number of weeks in a particular month

Tags: java, android, calendar

i want to get number of weeks in current month.That including the previous month's days in the last week and the first week days in the next month.

Something like this:

[image: Simple Isnt it?]

I want to use this in a certain gridview adapter on android and am trying to manipulate this code block:

```
            //FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK =0;
    int lastDay = month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int firstDay = (int) month.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int firstDayNextMonth = nextMonth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int lastDayNextMonth=nextMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int nextMonthdays=nextMonth.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();

    // figure size of the array
    if (firstDay == 1) {
        days = new String[lastDay + (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK * 6)];
    }

    else {
        days = new String[lastDay + firstDay - (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK + 1)];
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean for the week starting from Sunday and ending on Saturday specifically?

Comment: @Swapnil yes you're right

Comment: if tuesday is selected you need to get how many tuesdays in a month right?

Comment: @Ramkiran not exactly.My scenario may include tuesdays of the next month too.

Comment: Won't this work?: `int rows = Math.ceil(lastDay/7);`.

Comment: I have a question for you. I want you to look at the Jan 2010 calendar. What do you expect as number of weeks in that case?

Comment: @Nezam: Answer is full proof now. Need your nod.

Comment: @VendettaDroid you got your cake and i got mine.All Praises to Allah Alone

Comment: @Kristopher Not always. For example a 31 days month may have 1 or 2 days in the first row, then 4 rows at 7 days and 1 or 2 days in the 6th row. Yet Math.ceil(31 / 7) yields only 5. Also for a 28 days February your formula yields 4, but most often such a month takes 5 rows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WEEK_OF_YEAR attribute of the Calendar class can be useful for you. Ref: [Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Create a new date that will be the first day of the some month. Get the week of the year for this day, let say you got start value.

Create a new date that will be the last day of the given month. Get the week of the year for this day, so now you got end value.

Now end - start + 1 should be one that you want.

You may have to handle some corner case when the week overlaps to another year or similar. But I think once you get this right, you can do that with simple logic.

Here is simple example code. I think you can make it into function and pass whatever you want.

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        int start = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        Log.d("BLA BLA", "Value is " + start);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
        int end = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        //Above line will not work for December Month, use following line for this
        int end = isDecember?53:cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        Log.d("BLA BLA", "Value is " + end);
        Log.d("BLA BLA", "Num weeks:: " + (end - start +1 ));
```

**For Corner case:**

Corner case will only occur for the month of Januaray (E.g Jan 2010, Jan 2000) in those cases most of the days are part of the last week of the previous year so the start value will be 52 and end value will be 5. When this occurs check if,

```
          if(start > end) {
                numweeks = end + 1;
             }
```

P.S: Put it to different testing inputs that you got. Let me know If I can improve on it once you find any fault.

**And Even much simpler solution:**

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 11;i++){
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
            int maxWeeknumber = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            Log.d("LOG","max week number" + maxWeeknumber);
        }

        01-22 01:49:03.591: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.602: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.602: D/LOG(573): max week number6
        01-22 01:49:03.671: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.671: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.671: D/LOG(573): max week number6
        01-22 01:49:03.681: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.691: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.691: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.711: D/LOG(573): max week number5
        01-22 01:49:03.711: D/LOG(573): max week number5
```

**Simple solution works fine with corner cases:**

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 11;i++){
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, i);
            int maxWeeknumber = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            // Month value starts from 0 to 11 for Jan to Dec
            Log.d("LOG","For Month :: "+ i + " Num Week :: " + maxWeeknumber);
        }
```

Log:

```
        01-22 01:59:35.841: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 0 Num Week :: 6
        01-22 01:59:35.841: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 1 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.841: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 2 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.841: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 3 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.841: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 4 Num Week :: 6
        01-22 01:59:35.852: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 5 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.871: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 6 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.871: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 7 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.871: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 8 Num Week :: 5
        01-22 01:59:35.871: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 9 Num Week :: 6
        01-22 01:59:35.871: D/LOG(629): For Month :: 10 Num Week :: 5
```

Comment: Can you help me with that code block which i have provided.As you can see i am already getting some values which you're hinting at?

Comment: let me try to put it together for you as example

Comment: I have a question for you. I want you to look at the Jan 2010 calendar. What do you expect as number of weeks in that case?

Comment: Is this last piece of code which you gave corner case proof ? I think so

Comment: Yes it is, i checked corner cases for year 2010 and 2000 it works fine. I am about to put logs for that too. It is full proof code now ;)

Comment: `cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);` will return different values for different Locales. Initialize it with `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.YOUR_LOCALE);`.

Comment: @VendettaDroid you said "//Month value starts from 0 to 11 for Jan to Dec". Then value of i inside for loop should starts at 0 and end at 11 but (i < 11) means its only shows 0 to 10. I think it should be i<= 11.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I tried your last snippet (*works fine with corner cases*). My locale uses ISO weeks (start on Monday) and the correct numbers for those 11 months would be 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5 and 5. Your code printed 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4 and 5. That’s 64 % correct. A little bit better than tossing a coin.

Answer (score 10):

We can use the calendar class and then do something like

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
```

this will return the number of weeks in the current month

Comment: Nice & simple without bringing in quantum supremacy

Answer (score 8):

use WEEK_OF_MONTH will be better, no cross year issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  for (String m : new String[] { "2012-11", "2012-12", "2013-01", "2013-02", "2013-03",
              "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06" }) {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
      Date date = format.parse(m);
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      c.setTime(date);

      int start = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

      c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
      c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
      int end = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
      System.out.println(" # of weeks in " + format.format(c.getTime())
              + ": " + (end - start + 1));
  }
}
```

results:

```
# of weeks in 2012-11: 5
# of weeks in 2012-12: 6
# of weeks in 2013-01: 5
# of weeks in 2013-02: 5
# of weeks in 2013-03: 6
# of weeks in 2013-04: 5
# of weeks in 2013-05: 5
# of weeks in 2013-06: 6
```

Comment: You deserve the tick too chap.But as you can see an answer depends on how closely you adapt to the question of the questioner.

Answer (score 4):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work (I was frankly negatively surprised to see that no answer so far had suggested this).

```
public static int getTotalNumberOfWeeks(WeekFields wf, Temporal month) {
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(month);
    int firstWeekNumber = ym.atDay(1).get(wf.weekOfMonth());
    int lastWeekNumber = ym.atEndOfMonth().get(wf.weekOfMonth());
    return lastWeekNumber - firstWeekNumber + 1; // Both weeks inclusive
}
```

Let’s first try it with the example month from your question, January 2013, so we know that the expected result is 5. Since your weeks start on Sunday, we specify that too in the call:

```
    System.out.println(getTotalNumberOfWeeks(
            WeekFields.SUNDAY_START, YearMonth.of(2013, Month.JANUARY)));
```

Output is the expected:

> 5

For a newer example I am taking May 2021 (next month as of writing). Since where I live we use ISO weeks (starting on Monday), let’s try that too:

```
    System.out.println(getTotalNumberOfWeeks(
            WeekFields.ISO, YearMonth.of(2021, Month.MAY)));
```

> 6

If you want the weeks used in the default locale of your JVM, use `WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault())` as first argument. If you want the current month, you may pass `YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` as the second. I declared the second paramtere a `Temporal` for convenience. This allows you to pass a `LocalDate`, a `YearMonth`, a `ZonedDateTime`, any java.time class that defines a month and a year.

ISO 8601, the international standard probably used in the greater part of the world, defines week 1 of the month as the first week that contains at least 4 days of the month. This implies that up to three days in the beginning of the month may be in week 0. This is why the answers that only look at the maximum week number of the month break. Instead I subtract the minimum week number from the max and add 1 because we want both of those weeks included in the count.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: You did indeed work out all the details. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we know the first day of the month (Saturday, Sunday etc).

- If 1st day of the month is a `Sunday` and it's not a leap-year, then the (correction edit) `February` month will have only 4 weeks. Otherwise, in all the cases, it should have at least 5 and at most 6 weeks.
- Now, if your month starts on `Saturday`, you'll always have 6 weeks (excluding if it is February, when it there will be 5)
- Now, if your month starts on `Friday`, you'll have 6 weeks for months having 31 days and 5 for all others.
- For rest of the cases, it will always be 5 weeks.

Finding out the 1st day of the month shouldn't be difficult, you can use `Calendar` or other date/time utility library classes. However, I guess there could be cleaner solutions removing the corner cases and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I Guess Vendetta is providing a cleaner solution if he shows me a clean code to handle corner cases too.

Comment: September 1st, 2013 is a Sunday and at least in my part of the world, that month spans 6 weeks and not 4 as suggested by your first point. Remember that the first day of the week is locale specific, but even if the week starts on that Sunday, September 2013 would have had 5 weeks.

Comment: Correction: I wanted to mention February (in the context of leap year), but didn't actually do it. Do you see any other problems?

Comment: @Swapnil: Yes, as I already wrote, you are assuming that Sunday is the first day of the week. That's not necessarily true.

Comment: Didn't the asker mean exactly that? I asked him specifically about it in the comments below the question. I think I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it by "hand"

use this:

```
Date.prototype.getMonthWeek = function(monthAdjustement)
{    

    var firstDay = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 1).getDay();

    var returnMessage = (Math.ceil(this.getDate()/7) + Math.floor(((7-firstDay)/7)));

    return returnMessage;

}
```

Where `monthAdjustement` is just an Integer adjusting the month you seek compared to Today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Java's **Calendar API** is very useful for this kind of use case.
Ref link: [Calendar docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

I am assuming that you have a month's starting date.

1. we need to set Time(java.util.Date obj) by using setTime()
   because when you create an instance of Calendar class, it by default sets time to the ***machine's current time and date***.

   **if you don't need to calculate the total number of weeks for a particular month then you can simply avoid the first step.**
2. we just need to call getActualMaximum() for a field name called
   Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH.

   ```
   public static int getTotalNumberOfWeeks() throws ParseException {

       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

       Date monthStartingDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM- dd").parse("2021-04-01");

       calendar.setTime(monthStartingDate);

       return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
   }
   ```

You can check out more details for the given date In the console by printing Calendar's object as well.

Comment: I recommend we don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `WeekFields`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I tried your code with `2021-05-01`. In my locale May 2021 overlaps with 6 weeks: 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 and 22. Your method returned 5, so incorrect.

Comment: @denes-vaghani To correct the problem of reporting one week to short for May 2021, I suggest adapting the calendar to the OP scenario: he wants to count any number of days (also one day) as a valid week for the month. So May 31st must count as a valid week, and so May 1st and 2nd. To do so, set the calendar so it will count a valid week from as short as one day long. This is done by inserting `calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);` right after you get the Calendar instance.